# Naming conflict with Framework and class sharing a name

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've run into a situation where i have a `DataManager.framework` that includes the classes:   `DataManager`, `LocationManager` and `RecordingManager`

I'm unable to make Module based calls such as

```
let rec : DataManager.RecordingManager
```

because I'm running into a naming conflict between the `DataManager.framework` and `DataManager.class`

Is there a work around other than renaming either my class or framework?

Answer (score 0):

Ah-HA!

So what I did was rename my `DataManager` class to `XDataManager`

I then made a package level accessor:

```
public var sharedInstance { return XDataManager.sharedInstance }
```

This allows me to still keep my old code that accessed `DataManager.sharedInstance` working, while being able to differentiate between the package `DataManager` and the class `XDataManager`